# Reference for standardized histology rating criteria of microscope images

Tags: microscopy, histology, tissue

I am looking for a reference to a standard protocol for assessing the visual quality and diagnostic potential of a tissue sample that has been processed and stained for viewing under light microscope. What kinds of things are important to look for? For example the overall morphology, cellular outline, integrity of structures, nuclear details, lymphocytes and erythrocytes, etc...

I am looking for a paper that explains what things to look for in a well processed sample. Thank you

Comment: I think this question would be a better fit in Biology.SE because histology is much broader than medicine.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [1951 USAF resolution test chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1951_USAF_resolution_test_chart) (inline below). It has arrays of progressively smaller spatial frequency features. Just find the smallest feature that can be resolved and use this as a metric to compare to other brightfield microscopes in your facility.

[image: 1951 USAF resolution test chart]

Such charts are available from Thorlabs, Newport, and Edmund optics. Edmund also has a calculator to use with it which provides the resolution in line pairs per mm.

Comment: I have edited your answer to direct include the image and a link to wikipedia for the item, and the additional info you provided by comment. This is the kind of thing that I meant. Also note that while you have addressed issues of resolution, you have not really addressed the more relevant (IMO) biological side of the question.